# Simplest way to send files over network

Tags: networking, file-sharing, netcat

What is the simplest and most versatile way to send files over the network to other computers? By that I mean computers that other people are using at the moment. I don't think SSH works if the computer has an active session open.

So far I am using `netcat`, which works alright. But are there any other simple ways to do this? One problem I have with `netcat`, is that the receiver needs to know the file ending and has to come up with a name for the stream.

Comment: If you want to keep using `netcat` you can send a `tar` archive and extract it on the fly. That will solve the file name issue and it's more flexible. But in the end I guess `scp` or `rsync` is the easier option.

Comment: How would sending a tar and extracting it on the fly work?

Comment: I suppose that would be `netcat hostname | tar -x` in the directory where you want to put the files.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD.](https://xkcd.com/949)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're complicating your life needlessly. Use `scp`.

To transfer a file *myfile* from your local directory to directory */foo/bar* on machine *otherhost* as user *user*, here's the syntax: `scp myfile user@otherhost:/foo/bar`.

EDIT: It is worth noting that transfer via scp/SSH is encrypted while transfer via netcat or HTTP isn't. So if you are transferring sensitive files, always use the former.

Comment: Don't I need a password for `scp` of the user account?

Comment: Yes, of course. You need a password for the account `user@otherhost`.

Comment: No, you don't need a password if you use public key authentication

Comment: Ok, if you want to be picky, let's state that _you have to authenticate_ as `user@otherhost`.

Comment: Also, as a simplification, if your username is the same on both machines, you can exclude the username.  It'll still ask you for a password when applicable, though.

Comment: Setup ssh-agent and it will cache the authentication creds for duration of your session. In other words, you will only have to type the password once per session/login, not each time you use scp.

Comment: scp can put encryption performance bottleneck when using awfully slow machines

Comment: Such a no brainer, yet  didn't cross my mind at all! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

If you're happy with `netcat` you can work around the file name issue by
intruducing `tar`. This also simplifies sending multiple files at once as well
as sending directories.

On the sending side use:

```
tar cf - <files> | nc <host> <port>
```

And on the receiving side:

```
nc -l <port> | tar x
```

Another solution would be to use `rsync` or `scp`.

Comment: I usually add -q2 to the sending `netcat` as well, to make it shut down the connection at the end of the stream.

Comment: I fail to understand why this should be required. It does shut down automatically without the `-q` option.

Comment: That depends on which netcat implementation you use. There are implementations that only close one direction of the TCP stream when stdin closes, because the other direction may still be active.

Comment: `tar | ssh tar` also works very nicely in cases where scp falls down and rsync isn't available.

Answer (score 12):

You can also try

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8180
```

It will serve the files in directory in which it executed over HTTP, you can access it via Browser.

Comment: Or use darkhttpd when being dissatisfied with performance.

Comment: For Python 3: `python3 -m http.server <port>`.

Comment: See here for more information about this option: http://askubuntu.com/a/95607/42073

Comment: Thanks!  Perfect to getting some files onto a Windows test system

Answer (score 2):

Of course `ssh` works if another session is open. You can just do

```
ssh user@host cat /path/to/file.tar  > localfile.tar
```

Or, to copy to your local directory:

```
scp user@host:/path/to/file.tar .
```

Comment: Is it possible the other way around e.g. `ssh lubuntu '>newfile.txt' <file.txt` ?

Comment: @heemayl yes, to cat into a remote file, you would do `cat local.file | ssh user@host "cat > remote.file"`, or `ssh user@host "cat > remote.file" < local.file`.

Answer (score 0):

If both hosts are in the same LAN, you can use [woos](http://fex.belwue.de/fstools/woos.html).

It's extremly simple in usage.

If sender and receiver are ANYWHERE in the internet and you have to transfer BIG FILES, you should install F*EX:
http://fex.belwue.de/index.html

Comment: basic scp is also extremely simple, and a tool which is actually distributed, trusted and used by millions people, unlike these home-made tools which appear to be promoted by their author.